# Monitor with built-in USB, webcam not detected

Tags: usb, 22.04, multiple-monitors, webcam

I have **Asus BE24a monitor** connected via DisplayPort to Nvidia Quadro K2000.
The monitor has built-in line-in input, loudspeakers and 2 USB ports. The loudspeakers are detected by Ubuntu as output devices and I can stream audio there without a problem. According to the manual, **built-in USB ports** may be used as regular USB port to plug in auxiliary devices like card-readers, web cams etc.
I have **HP 4310 webcam**, which I'd like to be connected to one of the USB ports on the monitor. However, when I do, the webcam is not detected by the system.
However, the webcam can be detected normally when plugged in directly into the workstation. It seems not a driver problem, but Ubuntu not seeing webcam through the monitor.
I tried lsusb and lspci to no effect

```
root@station:~# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8002 Intel Corp. 8 channel internal hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:800a Intel Corp. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 17aa:1034 VIA Labs, Inc.          USB Hub                
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 17aa:1034 VIA Labs, Inc.          USB Hub                
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 062a:4101 MosArt Semiconductor Corp. Wireless Keyboard/Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I tried lsinput, which did not give anything related specifically to the webcam. Just some GPU related entries, like the one below

```
/dev/input/event14
   bustype : (null)
   vendor  : 0x0
   product : 0x0
   version : 0
   name    : "HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9"
   phys    : "ALSA"
   bits ev : (null) (null)
```

I did not find any relevant info how to use display as a hub in Ubuntu and any such issues either.
Anybody knows how I could make my webcam be detected through display? What else to try?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the back of your monitor. There should exist a number of USB ports. You have to connect these to your computer before connecting the webcam to the monitor.